# Android zoom in animation from visibility start state of View.GONE

Tags: android, animation, view, visibility

I have a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView and progress bar.
The starting state on the RelativeLayout is `View.Gone`.
Using an animation library (tried several so the problem isn't the libs), 
I'm trying to zoom in the RelativeLayout loader container.
I've tried for some time now to search my issue but couldn't find anything relevant, so I must be doing something wrong, and I would appreciate your help.

Here is a list of all of my attempts and their results:

- When the view starting state is `View.VISIBLE`, just before the animation, the loader is shown in its full size and then the zoom in animation starts (Because of this I tried starting state of `View.GONE`).
- When the view starting state is `View.GONE`, when the animation starts, there is a blink on start while executing the animation (I assume that its because of the visibilty change. When there is not change of the visibility I don't encounter this issue).
- I tried setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` as mentioned in some threads, but that didn't work.

The code of the animation is:

```
public void zoomInAnimation(final View view) {

    ViewAnimator
            .animate(view)
            .onStart(new AnimationListener.Start() {
                @Override
                public void onStart()
                {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
            .duration(400)
            .zoomIn()
            .start();

}
```

And my layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent_black"
            tools:context="il.co.cambium.sport5radio.fragments.MediaPlayerFragment">

<!-- Loader container -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mediaPlayerLoader"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="124dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <!-- Circular image view -->
    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        app:civ_border="true"/>

    <!-- Loader-->
    <fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:cpb_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cpb_max_sweep_angle="300"
        app:cpb_min_sweep_angle="10"
        app:cpb_stroke_width="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Video display -->
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/mediaPlayerSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<!-- Controls -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controlsRootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Minimize button + collapsed play button -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Close icon -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/videoBackBtn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_ripple_effect_player"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@mipmap/player_ic_minimize"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

            <!-- Button play -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/collapsedPlayPauseBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/round_ripple_effect_player"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_pause"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Title -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/videoPlayerTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Live dot -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentMediaPlayerBlinkingCircle"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!-- Poster -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mediaImage"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom controls -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/media_prev"
                style="@android:style/MediaButton.Previous"/>-->

            <!--<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/media_rew"
                style="@android:style/MediaButton.Rew"/>-->

            <!--<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/notification_ic_play"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_player"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
            style="@android:style/MediaButton.Play"-->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/media_play_pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_ripple_effect_player"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_pause"/>
            <!--style="@android:style/MediaButton.Pause"-->

            <!--<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_ffwd"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton.Ffwd"/>-->

            <!-- <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/media_next"
                 style="@android:style/MediaButton.Next"/>-->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentMediaPlayerProgressContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/media_position"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black_semi_transparent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/media_progress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/MyProgressBar"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/media_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black_semi_transparent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: @yash786 The starting state of the image there isn't GONE

Comment: Just try to implement that code you will see the Circular progressIcon initially with visibility gone at the starting state of the image once the image starting visible the Circular progressIcon will gone

Comment: @yash786
Even though the initial state was `invisible`, I still got the blink.
Any way changed it to `gone`...